# Can not see C drive ( windows installed ) in list of devices in Nautilus

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, nautilus, gparted

Let me tell how the problem started.

I needed more free space for D drive, so i extended free space for D drive from C drive by using the the function EXTEND of Mini Partition Tools Wizard. Then the process needed to reboot and when it rebooted it could not access to menu boot of options choosing Windows or Ubuntu ( GRUB -). So I recovered GRUB by following this method https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub and it loaded successfully.

I used gparted to check and see symbol "!" on /dev/sda2 where windows 7 is located. 
here are the image. it's safe. sorry for the inconvenience.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wie7B.png

Now, whenever I go to Nautilus to check devices and I can not see C drive as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very much likely that you might have extended your partition over a partition that didn't have enough space, so you might have overwritten some data.
However, thats not the only case. Probably nautilus is failing to pick up the C: drive.

So, for starters, try accessing **disks** as a superuser, that is, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal, and type in:

> **sudo gnome-disks**

After Disks opens, try mounting the C drive manually.
[image: Mounting a drive under gnome-disks]

If it doesn't work, try monting it again under sudo:

> **sudo mount /dev/sdaX**

..replacing X with the corresponding drive number for C.

Comment: thank you but it shows : "mount: can't find /dev/sda2 in etc/fstab or /etc/mtab" when i type "sudo mount /dev/sdaX". Can you show me more details about the 1st method, how to mount C manually ?

Comment: After opening disks under "sudo", go to the mount icon, that essentially looks like the ordinary "play button. I have updated the answer with a screenshot that shows how you mount manually.

Comment: oh, in my situation, partition 2 ( c drive - windows installed ) does not display "play" button. i think we can not use that way. how about "sudo mount". can you explain more.

Comment: If its not displaying, try mounting it as "read-only" to see if its accessible:

sudo mount -o -ro /dev/sdaX ~/folder

...where X is the corresponding drive letter for your C: drive, and "folder" is an empty folder in nautilus's home folder, whereon the drive will be mounted given that it has successfully opened in read-only mode

Comment: it doesn't work. i just see " mount: can't find /dev/sda2~/folder in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab "

Comment: You need to specify a directory to mount the file system at. I suggest you create a new one: `mkdir ~/drive_c`. Then you can mount: `sudo mount /dev/sda2 ~/drive_c`. If that results in an error, please report back with the message.

Comment: it displays : "mount: you must specify the file system type"

Comment: Use sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdaX ~/drive_c